# Why is my regex code not returning any result?

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code:

```
import re
word="ABCD 12345"
match=re.search(r"\d*",word)
print(match.group())
```

For this code, I am getting no output (no errors as well).

Kindly help. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

The `*` special character means "match *zero or more*". In other words, `\d*` is allowed to be a zero-length match – and because it's the only thing in your regex, the whole match is allowed to be zero-length.

It's true that `*` is greedy, and would return all digits *if* it actually got to the position where "12345" is present – for example `re.match(r"\d*", "12345")` would have returned the whole number:

```
>>> re.search(r"\d*", "12345")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='12345'>
```

But in your case, it doesn't actually get to that location in the string, instead it immediately decides that there's a match at position 0, length 0. Note the 'span' attribute:

```
>>> re.search(r"\d*", "ABCD 12345")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

You probably want to use `\d+` instead.

Comment: Beat me to it! I was also going to suggest `\d*$` which anchors to the _end_ of the string, or otherwise consuming the unwanted characters.

Comment: That would also work (if the number is always at the end), it depends on what OP is actually trying to find and where.